# Android: Setting a ListView to a Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-listview, navigation-drawer

This is what I want to have:

1. Populate a ListView with data I request from a server
2. Populate the ListView to a Navigation Drawer

I have populated the ListView with the data I requested and it's not empty. However I can't get it to populate the ListView to the Navigation Drawer.

```
ListView commentsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
CommentsAdapter adapter = new CommentsAdapter(HomeCategoryActivity.this, R.layout.comment_single, comments, fname, lname);
commentsList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The above code represents this:

[image]

And it's XML which is in main Layout:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:background="#2B2B2B"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

That adapter works and I populate the ListView successfully and not null. And then I assign a Navigation Drawer:

```
DrawerLayout rightDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_cat);
rightDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
```

XML of that:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_cat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="activity.classes.HomeCategoryActivity">
```

And finally I dont know how to attach the ListView to the Drawer..

What am I doing wrong? I think it does not require an adapter to assign the ListView to the Drawer?

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `ListView` as the second child of the `DrawerLayout` The first child will be the content when the drawer is off-screen and the second child will be the content visible when the drawer is on-screen (aka the drawer itself).

Also, by doing this:

```
commentsList.setAdapter(adapter_right);
```

You are resetting the adapter (the source of the data) on the list view so you will not see the data you originally had set with your `CommentsAdapter`.

See the example xml file on the [Google DrawerLayout Dev Page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

Comment: Did the second child of the `DrawerLayout` must be the type of `ListView`?This design is ridiculous!